# Is this code as insecure as it looks?

Tags: javascript, pci-dss, html

The company I work for is looking for a payment processor. Ideally we want a fully and seamlessly integrated solution. I came across this from one of the recommended companies I had to look in to

This is from a sample page. I don't have a sandbox account yet to actually try anything out (but I requested one).

Here's the immediate piece of code I have an issue with:

```
<input type="button" onclick="TAMPER_PROOF_SEAL.value = hex_md5(TPS.SECRET_KEY.value + ACCOUNT_ID.value)" value="Generate API Signature">
```

The rest here is most of the HTML from the 'sample page' sands header and body tags.

```
<table border=1>
 <TR><TD colspan=2><CENTER><B>company.js API Signature Generator</B></CENTER></TD></TR>
<form name="TPS">
 <TR>
    <TD>SECRET_KEY:</TD>
    <TD><input type="text" value="" name="SECRET_KEY" align="top" size="50"> <font size="-2" color="RED">API Sig1</font></TD>
 </TR>
</form>
<form name="main" method="post">
 <TR>
    <TD>ACCOUNT_ID:</TD>
    <TD>
        <input type="text" value="" name="ACCOUNT_ID" align="top" size="50"> <font size="-2" color="RED">API Sig2</font><br>
        12-digit Company 2.0 Account ID
    </TD>
 </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>API Signature:</TD>
    <TD>
        <input type="text" value="" name="TAMPER_PROOF_SEAL" align="top" size="50"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="TAMPER_PROOF_SEAL.value = hex_md5(TPS.SECRET_KEY.value + ACCOUNT_ID.value)" value="Generate API Signature"><br>
        MD5 hash of Secret Key and Account ID
    </TD>
 </TR>

</TABLE>
</form>
```

It's a 'custom' MD5 hashing library of theirs.

This strikes me as being weak as hell security.

- A. MD5 hashses are terrible
- B. It's trivial to ignore the hash code anyway, and our "secret" is
  out. I'm reading through more documentation to make sure it's not as
  dumb as it looks.

Is Direct Posting still a sound idea? Authorize.NET
   seemed to have a great one with Accept.JS. Unfortunately their costs
   will kill us.

Or this piece, showing more end to end functionality. I don't see the security:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Company Encryption &amp; Tokenization</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<!--
HTML INSTRUCTIONS
====================================
Place data-encrypted-name="INPUT_NAME" attribute on all form controls to be encrypted. See below for acceptable values.
Do not include name="" attribute on form controls with data-encrypted-name="":

    CREDIT CARDS
    ====================================
    Card Number
    data-encrypted-name="CARD_ACCOUNT"

    Security Code
    data-encrypted-name="CARD_CVV2"

    2 digit month
    data-encrypted-name="EXPMO"

    2 digit year
    data-encrypted-name="EXPYR"

    4 digit date: MMYY
    data-encrypted-name="CARD_EXPIRE"

    ACH
    ====================================
    Checking or Savings: C/S
    data-encrypted-name="ACH_ACCOUNT_TYPE"

    Account Number
    data-encrypted-name="ACH_ACCOUNT"

    Routing Number
    data-encrypted-name="ACH_ROUTING"
--> 

<!-- Set "action" to URL of script on merchant's web server that will receive token. -->
<form id="payment-form" method="post" class="form" action="***URL of script on merchant's server goes here***">
    <input type="hidden" name="MODE" value="LIVE">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Info</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="NAME1">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="NAME1" name="NAME1" value="John"><br>
            <input type="text" id="NAME2" name="NAME2" value="Doe">
        </p>        
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Credit Info</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="AMOUNT">Amount</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT" value="5.00">              
        </p>            
        <p>
            <label for="CARD_ACCOUNT">Credit Card Number</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="CARD_ACCOUNT" data-encrypted-name="CARD_ACCOUNT" value="4111111111111111">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="CARD_CVV2">CVV Code</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="CARD_CVV2" data-encrypted-name="CARD_CVV2" value="123">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="EXPMO">Month</label>
            <select id="EXPMO" data-encrypted-name="EXPMO">
                <option value="01">01</option>
                <option value="02">02</option>
                <option value="03">03</option>
                <option value="04">04</option>
                <option value="05">05</option>
                <option value="06">06</option>
                <option value="07">07</option>
                <option value="08">08</option>
                <option value="09">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>

            <label for="EXPYR">Year</label>
            <select data-encrypted-name="EXPYR" id="EXPYR">                                                 
                <option value="16">2016</option>
                <option value="17">2017</option>
                <option value="18">2018</option>
                <option value="19">2019</option>
                <option value="20">2020</option>
                <option value="21">2021</option>
                <option value="22">2022</option>
                <option value="23">2023</option>
                <option value="24">2024</option>
                <option value="25">2025</option>
                <option value="26">2026</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
    <div class="form-response"></div>
</form>

<!-- [if using jquery: not required to use Company API] -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- [@end if using jquery] -->

<!-- [production] -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.fake.com/v3/company.js"></script>
<!-- [@end production] -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($) {

        /* Company Set Credentials for Encryption & Tokenization
         * Identifies Account ID & API Signature
         * @param {string} accountID (required) - Account ID
         * @param {string} apiSignature (required) - API Signature
         *
         * Company.setCredentials(accountID, apiSignature);
         *
         * ========================================
         */          
        Company.setCredentials("***Gateway account ID goes here***", "***API Signature goes here***");

        /* Company Callback 
         * Function is called after Company.createToken completes
         * @param {object} response - json response from api call           
         * @param {string} error - if unable to connect to api 
         * ========================================
         */                          
        var callback = function(response, error) {
            // cache form id
            var $form = $('#payment-form');
            // show response
            if (error) {
                // if unable to connect to api
                $form.find('.form-response').text(error);
            } else {
                if (response.STATUS !== '1') {
                    // Show form errors from api response
                    $form.find('.form-response').text(response.MESSAGE);            
                } else {
                    // success message
                    $form.find('.form-response').text(response.MESSAGE);
                    // re-submit form to server
                    $form.get(0).submit();
                }
            }
            // re-enable submit button
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        };

        // Event Listener Creates Token on submit
        $('#payment-form').on('submit',function(e) {

            // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action 
            // also prevent form submit when js error is thrown
            e.preventDefault();

            // cache form id
            var $form = $(this);

            // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);


           /* Company Create Token  
            * Encrypts sensitive data, creates Precalculated Tamper Proof Seal and Token
            * @param {object/string} data (required)- form id (to get data from) of plain js 'payment-form' or jquery $('#payment-form') or...
            * js object {CARD_ACCOUNT: '4111111111111111', CARD_CVV2: '123', CARD_EXPIRE: '0824'}
            * @param {function} callback (required) - Name of function to be called after encryption & tokenization complete  
            * @param {object} debug @property {boolean} (optional) - used with form id...
            * Shows 2 input fields to displays values before and after encryption when form id is passed. 
            * Also shows console warnings if data-encrypted-name is not a valid api name                           
            *       
            * Company.createToken(data, callback):
            *
            * ======================================== */
            Company.createToken($form, callback);
            // Company.createToken('payment-form', callback, {debug: true});
            // Company.createToken({CARD_ACCOUNT: '4111111111111111', CARD_CVV2: '123', CARD_EXPIRE: '0828', NAME1: 'John', NAME2: 'Doe'}, callback);
            // Company.createToken({PAYMENT_TYPE: 'ACH', ACH_ACCOUNT:'123456789', ACH_ROUTING: '123123123', NAME1: 'Jane', NAME2: 'Doe'}, callback);


        });
    });

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We're not a code review site.

Comment: 1) Are you supposed to tell us that it's BluePay? I hope the free trial isn't under NDA... 2) So the user types the secret key, and the button's OnClick hashes that together with the AccountID to make a "tamper-proof-seal; 2a) how does the user get the secret key? 2b) what is the tamper proof seal used for? I agree this is a red flag, but it's not necessarily terrible depending on how this fits into the bigger picture.

Comment: Well, this is subjective.  Use of API key and an associated secret key is quite common, it is the admin job to secure the connection between the communication.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth It was open code on their website, no NDA

Comment: @Joshua.J Stackoverflow told me to post here and closed the question

Comment: @mootmoot I agree. I'm comparing this to Authorize.NET's Accept.JS. They have a special public key and means of generating unique forms. I don't see that here. This is supposed to the the SAQ-AE direct post JS solution. I don't see how this could be super secure.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I'll yank the name from the code. But this was available on their website, no NDA etc. Otherwise I would have omitted the details originally.

Comment: Perhaps the correct question should be :  is the API token and secret key is guessable and easily hijacked.

Comment: @mootmoot As in; the token returned by the company? I would hope not. I just got a sandbox account 30 minutes ago. I won't be able to mess with it for most of the day. I will later in the evening and really see this in action.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot perform code audits. You *could* turn this into a couple specific questions about the approach, but we can't just review the code for you.

Comment: Honestly, there are myriad issues to be concerned about when evaluating a payment processor. How their API key is generated is not in the top 10.

Comment: @schroeder SO voted the question closed and told me I had to bring it here.

Comment: @JonahBenton Yeah, I've been going through so many different things with this processor, and several others. My company is in a cart before the horse situation. They built the full front end and integration into our systems, and _now_ want to find a PP. Of course they're seeing how much research goes into it. We're supposed to go live Aug 31. I hate this approach to programming. This project started before I was at the company. I've said the end goal date is a fairy tale at this point. I would love to hit it, but I have doubts.

Comment: @kevingreen I hear you. It's about security approaches, which is better here than there, but it is too "read this code and tell me what you think" more than "this bit right here, does this meet the goal of X considering Y and Z?"

Comment: @schroeder That seems fair. All this is mostly new to me. I know enough about security to know I want someone else to manage our customer account info to keep our PCI-DSS exposure low. But we need to keep our app as "seamless" as possible. That's been beaten into my head from day 1. I'll attempt to create a test app, then maybe I can ask more specific security questions, and less code analysis questions.

Comment: @kevingreen here's some background and a more specific question for you to ask.  They are basically taking `MD5(account_id+api_key)` to generate a public key.  That first code snippet of theirs is not meant to be used in production - it just helps you generate `MD5(account_id+api_key)` which is the "API Signature"  they use to authenticate the credit card transactions at actual checkout.

Comment: The potential problem is that the public key which anyone can scrape off your website is derived from your account id **and** api key.  As a result if they can "reverse" your public key to get back your api key, they have full access to your account.  So effectively what you want to know is: Can someone brute force this public key to get my API token and, if so, how dangerous is that for my account?

Comment: @kevingreen feel free to ping me here if you post some new questions